# magento how to change cart account in checkout page

Tags: magento

in product detail page, the product price is 50 dollar, I use JavaScript change the price to 80 dollar, but when add to cart, **it is still 50 dollar in checkout page**.  how to let it still 80 dollar in checkout page?

Answer (score 0):

You need use "sales_quote_add_item" magento event to update the product price in cart session.
You have to make a custom module for that purpose.

Create a file in app/etc/modules/Company_All.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <config>   <modules>
    <Company_Product>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <active>true</active>
    </Company_Product>   </modules> </config>
```

Create configuration file for our module file in app/code/local/Company/Product/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <config>   <global>
    <models>
        <product>
             <class>Company_Product_Model</class>
        </product>
    </models>
    <events>
      <sales_quote_add_item><!--Event to override price after adding product to cart-->
        <observers>
          <company_product_price_observer><!--Any unique identifier name -->
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Company_Product_Model_Price_Observer</class><!--Our observer class name-->
            <method>update_book_price</method><!--Method to be called from our observer class-->
          </company_product_price_observer>
        </observers>
      </sales_quote_add_item>
    </events>   </global> </config>
```

Create our observer file in app/code/local/Company/Product/Model/Price/Observer.php

```
class Company_Product_Model_Price_Observer{
    public function update_book_price(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $quote_item = $observer->getQuoteItem();

        //if(){ //your logic goes here
            $customprice = 50;
        //}
        $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customprice);
        $quote_item->save();
        return $this;
    }

}
```